# Convert date string into proper format

Tags: ios, dateformatter

I am getting a response from a server and there is a date string I need to convert into a date:

> Thu Jun 29 07:15:25 +0000 2017

I am trying to convert the string into a human readable format. Can anyone suggest how to convert this string into date?

Comment: You can use date formatter to format date and time.

Comment: You need to specify the desired output format.

Comment: @SushilSharma  can you please suggest how to implement this. I am unable to write date format for 'Thu Jun 29'

Comment: Your output format should be "EEE, MMM d"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the date string into a `Date` object using a `DateFormatter`, then create a string from that `Date` using another `DateFormatter` with the output format you want to use.

```
let created_at = "Thu Jun 29 07:15:25 +0000 2017"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
guard let date = df.date(from: created_at) else {return}
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d"
let outputDate = outputFormatter.string(from: date)
```

If you want to know what date formats look like, use [NSDateFormatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com), which has an interactive interface where you can play around with different date formats and have examples of most common formats as well.

Comment: Please change output format to  "EEE, MMM d". will achieve required answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can format it in **"Thu Jun 29"**

```
-(NSString *)formatCreatedAt:(NSString *)createdAt
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:createdAt];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd"];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    return stringFromDate;
}
```

Pass the value of `created_at` in this method and the output will be returned in your specified format.