# Formatting NSDate Received from Php

Tags: objective-c

Received date from server 
2017-10-27T17:40:56.0000000

I want to Convert into This Formate 
2017-10-27 17:40:00 +0000

I'm Using This Code But Out Is

```
NSString *str = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".0000000" withString:@""];
// convert to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
```

2017-10-27 12:40:56 +0000

It's wrong Please Help Me

Comment: Let me guess, you timezone has 5h difference from UTC?

Comment: Please Set this Formate How Will i Get Right Date

Comment: look into this question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822008/convert-date-string-into-proper-format

Comment: Server send me right time on my time but after converting facing issue